# PLS-00306 Error: How to find the wrong argument?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, datatypes, plsql, parameter

**PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'string'**

> Cause: This error occurs when the named subprogram call cannot be matched to any declaration for that subprogram name. The subprogram name might be misspelled, a parameter might have the wrong datatype, the declaration might be faulty, or the declaration might be placed incorrectly in the block structure. For example, this error occurs if the built-in square root function SQRT is called with a misspelled name or with a parameter of the wrong datatype.
>
> Action: Check the spelling and declaration of the subprogram name. Also confirm that its call is correct, its parameters are of the right datatype, and, if it is not a built-in function, that its declaration is placed correctly in the block structure.

How do I quickly identify the wrong argument?

I have a stored-procedure with dozens of parameters. Is there an easy way to check the differences between the used and defined procedure? I don't want to check it line by line..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there's really no shortcuts here.  Examine things in the following order:

1. Check the procedure name.
2. Check the number of parameters.
3. Check the types of the parameters.
4. Check the parameter names.

Comment: Also check the parameter names if calling them by name. That just caught me out.

Comment: checking the name of parameters is the key for me, thanks.

Comment: It could be the Object type

Comment: I spent about 4 hours debugging this error today.  In my case it was because the return value parameter wasn't first.  So make sure that one is added first before the others.  (Even though I was using named parameters, it still needed to be first)